# Covering all the bases with Form Validation, Client/Server - What is best way?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

I know there are many methods of validating forms on both client and server side but I was wondering what was the best practice?

Currently, I have Javascript functions validating form input fields 'on the fly' with onkeyup/onblur functions like so:

(Partial code:)

```
<p class="form-registerUserName">
    <div class="upperLabel">
        <label for="registerUserName">User Name</label>
        <span class="required">*</span>
    </div>
    <input
        id="registerUserName"
        name="registerUserName"
        type="text"
        size="24"
        maxlength="24"
        value="<?php echo $_SESSION['registerUserName'];?>"
        onkeyup="validateName()"
        onblur="checkDuplicateName(); validateName()"
    >
    <label for="registerUserName" class="hint" id="registerUserNameHint"></label>
</p>
```

With Javascript functions like:

```
function validateName() {
    userName = document.getElementById("registerUserName").value.trim();
    re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,30}$/;

    if (userName==="") {
        document.getElementById('registerUserName').style.borderColor="red";
        document.getElementById('registerUserNameHint').innerHTML = 'required';
    } else if (!re.test(userName)) {
        document.getElementById('registerUserName').style.borderColor="red";
        document.getElementById('registerUserNameHint').innerHTML = 'only alphanumeric characters and _';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("registerUserName").setAttribute("style","border-color: rgb(221,221,221) rgb(241,241,241) rgb(241,241,241) rgb(221,221,221);");
        document.getElementById('registerUserNameHint').innerHTML = '';
    }
} //validateName()
```

..So that the input box turns red and shows a hint on the side of the box if it does not validate.

So my question was - What is the best way to prevent the form from submission to my (Mysqli) database when the user hits submit?

(and second question..) Do I run an additional php server-side script after client-side validation has cleared?

Some ways I imagined to accomplish this is by having my Javascript functions set a Session variable that indicates an error condition, and not allow a submit if there was.

I am not certain how to do that, or how I set up my 'submit' to *not work* unless the error condition was cleared.

Would appreciate any help on that.

Then do I re-validate the same data (in the same manner) with php again, after a successful client-side validation before inserting into my database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should never "trust" the client.  Client side validation can easily be circumvented.  *Always* validate on the server as well.  Client side validation is just a nice addition to improve the user experience, but it will never replace a proper server side validation.

Comment: _“Do I run an additional php server-side script after client-side validation has cleared?”_ – of course you do, because for all you know, there __is__ no client-side validation … if you were even to _assume_ for a second, that any request reaching your server must have been send by something like a “browser”, you would be fundamentally __wrong__ already. (Why-o-why do we have to say this over and over again …?)

Comment: _“What is the best way to prevent the form from submission to my (Mysqli) database when the user hits submit?”_ – react to the submit _event_, do validation – and then cancel the event (preventDefault) when validation fails. That too, of course, is everything else but “new”, been discussed uncountable times already.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will look into it. I'm sure some of these things have been discussed but problem is finding those particular discussions.

Comment: Should I use a session variable to flag an error condition (if the javascript validation functions find an error) to use to condition the submit? .. or just skip that altogether and just do the server side validation upon submit? I guess it would be redundant if I'm doing the server side validation regardless..

Answer (score 0):

First off, always do server-side validation!

Second, HTML5 form validation is well supported.
Examples: http://html5pattern.com/

You can then use CSS for validation styling.

Comment: Ok thanks. But any hint on my particular situation where I am using Javascript for my client side validation? In particular I am trying to set an error condition w my javascript functions and not allow a submit upon any error conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Structure your validation with this logic:

```
   if validateName() {
      document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }
    // if returns true (passed validation) then submit

//validate on click of submit button or on submit   
 function validateName() {
        userName = document.getElementById("registerUserName").value.trim();
        re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,30}$/;

        if (userName==="") {
            document.getElementById('registerUserName').style.borderColor="red";
            document.getElementById('registerUserNameHint').innerHTML = 'required';
            **return false;**
        } else if (!re.test(userName)) {
            document.getElementById('registerUserName').style.borderColor="red";
            document.getElementById('registerUserNameHint').innerHTML = 'only alphanumeric characters and _';
            **return false;**
       ........ so forth
          else { 
             return true;
         }
```

Comment: javascript is used in like 99% of browsers.. so unless you're worried about the other 1% right now, then this is OK

Comment: if you do care - here's a link to get you started: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp

Comment: Thanks for this idea. However, validate functions are run during onblur, onkeyup events. so for me to condition the submit, I have to run all of the validation functions for every field all over again during submit. Now looking into setting window object / global variable since session variable with js needs AJAX or something like that.

Comment: in that case you can simply set the submit button to disabled if any input fails validation onblur, onkeyup

Comment: keep in mind " run all of the validation functions for every field all over again during submit " happens in a split second